# How to fix scrollable content size ambiguity in xcode 11 using auto layout beta 7 UIKIT

Tags: xcode, view, uiscrollview

When using Auto Layout, I am unable to set up a simple UIScrollView in my view controller in Xcode 11 beta 7. I know that I must constrain the scroll view to the edges, and then set the scroll view width and height equal to the width and height of the entire view that contains the scroll view. However, I am not getting the option to set equal widths and heights when I attempt to do so.

When I do the right-click-drag from the scroll view to the entire main view, I get the following options:

Leading Space to Safe Area
Top Space to Safe Area
Trailing Space to Safe Area
Bottom Space to Safe Area
Center Horizontally in Safe Area
Center Vertically in Safe Area
In other videos, there is an "Equal Widths" and "Equal Heights" option that I don't seem to have.

Am I doing something wrong, or did Apple change the way scroll views work in Xcode 11?

I'm using beta 7 currently

Comment: I am waiting for answers. Do you solved?

Answer (score 14):

I was finally able to successfully add a UIScrollView using storyboards in Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a) after much trial and error.

You can add the scroll view directly to the root UIView of the VC or, if you needed to, add it to another UIView under the root view as needed by your UI Design. Constrain the UIScrollView parents normally for whatever your needs are.

Here is the key : when you add the UIScrollView to the storyboard, click on the Size Inspector with the UIScrollView selected. You have to **UNCHECK** the box that says **"Content Layout Guides"**.

If you do this you can set the scroll view's contraints normally (I did 0-0-0-0 to superview). Then I added a UIView to the scrollview and set it's constraints to 0-0-0-0 and a height of 900 (which is what I wanted). 
This will give you constraint errors in red when you set them. They will be fixed by setting the width of the UIView equal to the width of the UIScrollView.

Set the UIView width equal to the width of the UIScrollView view by Ctrl-right clicking on the UIView, dragging to the UIScrollView, and selecting the "Equal Widths" option. This should get rid of your constraint errors.

You actually can then go back to the UISCrollView Size Inspector and check the "Content Layout Guides" checkbox, no constraint errors will appear.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the content layout guides in scrollview properties.
Hope it helps.. :)

[image]